# simple PLSQL (oracle) syntax question

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have this statement:

```
SELECT passwdlib.piv_insertPasswd(:A1, :A2) 
  FROM DUAL
```

I am guessing that `piv_insertPasswd` is the name of function or SP, and passwdlib is the user name. Am i right? If not what is each component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`passwdlib` could be a package name. See http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/09_packs.htm

Otherwise, it's a schema name.

Comment: Most likely are right. My sys admin handed me something to debug and I found that statement in the code. I checked the database and there is no such package. Maybe I should check with him to get the rest of the items I need to proceed.

Comment: @Haoest `passwdlib` could also be a public synonym for a different package name

Comment: How can you say that without an investigation in the dictionary?It could be also an object type

Answer (score 2):

It is more likely that `passwdlib` is the package name, and that `piv_insertPasswd` is the name of the function within the package.

Answer (score 2):

Schema, package, object, synonym.

```
select object_type
from   user_objects uo
where  uo.OBJECT_NAME = 'PASSWDLIB'

select typecode
from   user_types ut
where  ut.type_name = 'PASSWDLIB'

select *
from   USER_METHOD_PARAMS um
where  um.type_name = 'PASSWDLIB'
```

---

**2° section**:  added after the post was marked as answered.
I think the correct method in this case is to query the dictionary, without it we only try to guess!

Test the object option.

```
CREATE TYPE TPerson AS OBJECT (
  idno           NUMBER,
  first_name     VARCHAR2(20),
  last_name      VARCHAR2(25),
  email          VARCHAR2(25),
  phone          VARCHAR2(20),

  static FUNCTION getDetails  return varchar2);
/

create type body TPerson as

    static function getDetails return varchar2 is
    begin           
        return 'I am TPerson type ';
    end;
end;
/

select TPerson.getDetails() from dual;
```

Output

```
 select TPerson.getDetails() from dual;  

 TPERSON.GETDETAILS()
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 I am TPerson type
```

The investigation

```
select object_type,uo.*
from   user_objects uo
where  uo.OBJECT_NAME = 'TPERSON';


OBJECT_TYPE         OBJECT_NAME                                                                      SUBOBJECT_NAME                  OBJECT_ID DATA_OBJECT_ID OBJECT_TYPE         CREATED     LAST_DDL_TIME TIMESTAMP           STATUS  TEMPORARY GENERATED SECONDARY  NAMESPACE EDITION_NAME
------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------ ---------- -------------- ------------------- ----------- ------------- ------------------- ------- --------- --------- --------- ---------- ------------------------------
TYPE                TPERSON                                                                                                              23020                TYPE                02/08/2011  02/08/2011 07 2011-08-02:07:50:57 VALID   N         N         N                  1 
TYPE BODY           TPERSON                                                                                                              23021                TYPE BODY           02/08/2011  02/08/2011 07 2011-08-02:07:50:57 VALID   N         N         N                  2



select typecode,ut.*
from   user_types ut
where  ut.type_name = 'TPERSON';


TYPECODE                       TYPE_NAME                      TYPE_OID                         TYPECODE                       ATTRIBUTES    METHODS PREDEFINED INCOMPLETE FINAL INSTANTIABLE SUPERTYPE_OWNER                SUPERTYPE_NAME                 LOCAL_ATTRIBUTES LOCAL_METHODS TYPEID
------------------------------ ------------------------------ -------------------------------- ------------------------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----- ------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ---------------- ------------- --------------------------------
OBJECT                         TPERSON                        711EFA23BE614F1BAFE0D741324DB215 OBJECT                                  5          1 NO         NO         YES   YES
```